# c++ insert empty vector can not use braces

Tags: c++, vector, std

Codes below doesnt' works properly, when I reference to `it`, it causes `Member call on null pointer error`,  if it's not supported, why it allow the use of `insert(end, {})`(No compile error).

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> vv;
    auto it = vv.insert(vv.end(), {});
    cout << it->size() << endl;
}
```

When I changed `{}` `to vector<pair<int, int>>`, no error shows and print `0`.

Solved by comments, It calls `iterator insert( const_iterator pos, std::initializer_list<T> ilist )`, So change it to `insert(end, {{}})` could work.

Comment: No compile error doesn't mean stuff works as you think it does. In c++ you can write so many things without getting a compilation error

Comment: I guess it uses [iterator insert( const_iterator pos, std::initializer_list<T> ilist );](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) instead of the intended `iterator insert( const_iterator pos, const T& value );`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `auto it = vv.insert(vv.end(), {});` is using the form [`iterator insert( const_iterator pos, std::initializer_list<T> ilist );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert).

As int the line `auto it = vv.insert(vv.end(), {});`, the initlizer list have no element so no element is inserted in the vector `vv`.

As there is no element is inserted so `it` is same as `vv.end()` for which it is invalid to deference.

You can verify it via checking the length of `vv` after insertion. See [sample code here](https://ideone.com/c7Sijq) to check it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [cppreference – std::vector<T,Allocator>::insert()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), all flavors of `insert()` return the iterator of first inserted element or the insertion position if nothing was inserted.

In OPs exposed MCVE:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    vector<vector<pair<int, int>>> vv;
    auto it = vv.insert(vv.end(), {});
    cout << it->size() << endl;
}
```

the line

```
auto it = vv.insert(vv.end(), {});
```

doesn't use the
`iterator insert( const_iterator pos, const T& value );`
as it might be expected but the
`iterator insert( const_iterator pos, std::initializer_list<T> ilist );`.

Hence, there are 0 elements inserted and the `insert()` returns the `end()` iterator which was passed.

So,

```
cout << it->size() << endl;
```

accesses the contents of `end()` which is Undefined Behavior.

I made a small sample to demonstrate this:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct Container: std::vector<T> {
  using typename std::vector<T>::iterator;
  using typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator;
    
  iterator insert( const_iterator pos, const T& value )
  {
    std::cout << "insert single value\n";
    return std::vector<T>::insert(pos, value);
  }
  
  iterator insert( const_iterator pos, std::initializer_list<T> ilist )
  {
    std::cout << "insert initializer list\n";
    return std::vector<T>::insert(pos, ilist);
  }
};

using namespace std;
int main() {
    Container<vector<pair<int, int>>> vv;
    auto it = vv.insert(vv.end(), {});
    cout << /*it->*/vv.size() << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
insert initializer list
0
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f102c881c3a16452)

**Note:**

I'm aware that it's, at least, bad style to overload `std::vector`.
I did this exceptionally to show the used function call (and I didn't have a better idea how to achieve this).

Comment: I get it now, since his answer is earlier and your repu is much higer than @cse, I accepted his answer.

Comment: @BAKEZQ It's your decision. ;-)

Comment: Apprexiate your detailed explanation. I could found this if I check more carefull  in cppref. I  never checked details of the initializer list but most of time it worked as waht i expected, however, this time my intution failed.